# Slow View rendering rails in 3.2.16 with blank action and simple template.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues tracking down a slow page render in a single page website. The page takes about 300ms to render, which isn't a deal breaker, but is unacceptable to me since the page is essentially static.

Controller:

```
def index
  @count = User.count unless Rails.cache.exist? "views/home_page"
end
```

The view renders 2 partials and uses simple form. There is 1 DB query in the view. I cached the entire page with:

```
- cache("home_page", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
 ... CODE
```

My gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

gem 'pg'
gem "haml-rails"
gem "rolify"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "font-awesome-rails", "3.2.1.3"
gem 'animatecss'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "mechanize"
gem 'textacular', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-typeahead-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "unicorn-rails"
gem "wice_grid", '3.4.0'

group :assets do
  gem 'backstretch-rails'
  gem 'asset_sync'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'jazz_hands'
end
```

And my unicorn config is:

```
worker_processes 4

working_directory "#{ENV['RAILS_STACK_PATH']}"

listen "/tmp/web_server.sock", :backlog => 64

timeout 30

pid '/tmp/web_server.pid'

stderr_path "#{ENV['RAILS_STACK_PATH']}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{ENV['RAILS_STACK_PATH']}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
    GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

check_client_connection false

before_fork do |server, worker|
    old_pid = '/tmp/web_server.pid.oldbin'
    if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
        begin
            Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
        rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
            # someone else did our job for us
        end
    end

    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

There are a couple things that bother me that I can't figure out:

1. If the page is cached, why does the view render so slowly?
2. Why does the index take up such a large amount of time comparatively when it has less code than the partials and only renders haml (with no db queries).

Here is a server trace:

```
16:28:05.783 Processing by UsersController#index as */*
16:28:05.783 Cache exist: views/home_page
16:28:05.783 Cache read: views/home_page ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
16:28:05.783 Read fragment views/home_page 12.6ms
16:28:05.783 Rendered users/index.html.haml within layouts/application (22.5ms)
16:28:05.783 Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.6ms)
16:28:06.183 Completed 200 OK in 372.5ms (Views: 371.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here are some new relic traces.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZSR.png

Finally, I'm using an amazon medium instance.

Thanks!

Jon

Comment: Post 3.2.12 apps have been reported to have this issue of taking longer to render views for no particular reason. Downgrading to 3.2.12 solved the problem for me.

Comment: I was able to shave off about 70ms a couple of months ago by switching to 3.2.12 -- made a ticket in github about this, although I'd prefer security over speed. Sadly, I dont think its the root cause of my issue.